# SQL query to check all records of employee

Tags: sql

I wanted to check all employees and location. One location is having multiple employees. So my condition is i want all locations where all employee status is inactive.

Like eg emp table is

```
EmpId loc status
123  ABC active
124 ABC active
125  ABC inactive
234  PQR inactive
```

Result should be

```
Empid loc status 
234 PQR inactive
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *location* where all statuses are inactive, I would recommend `group by`:

```
select loc
from t
group by loc
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'inactive';
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, i will try that. However if i have a multiple status then in clause will work here?  Like if i wanted to know inactive and hold employees?

Comment: @user3528745 . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you have asked.  If you have another question, then ask it as *another* question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
SELECT DISTINCT loc, status
  FROM my_table
 WHERE loc NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT loc WHERE status = 'active);
```

This will give you all locations which are not active.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `distinct` in the sub-select is useless

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name-  why? there can be duplicate loc with status = 'active'. DISTINCT will give a distinct list for IN to search for.

Comment: I dont think it will check all of the employees. Like it will give locations where status is inactive but a location can be associated with many employees. I dont want A loaction where atleast one emp is active

Comment: @user3528745 - thats what i expect the output be. have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, i doesnt give expected results